# C++ Macro Magic: getting for every macro parameter, the parameter count number

Tags: c++, macros

I've to write a lot of code like this.

```
foo.setArg(0, arg_0);
foo.setArg(1, arg_1);
...
foo.setArg(n, arg_n);
```

Where n is compile-time specific and the arg_n are of different types;

I want a variadic macro which i can call like this
    `MACRO_MAGIC(arg_0,arg_1,...,arg_n)`

I know how to get the total number of arguments but i didn't succeed in getting it managed.

**Edit:** from (non-sense) statement n is runtime specific to compile-time specific

Comment: Pre-processing (i.e. macro expansion) is compile time. You cannot use runtime variable to expand a macro dynamically.

Comment: absolutely right: see edit

Comment: boost::preprocessor is your friend (or your enemy, depending on how you look at it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
#define IT_CHOOSER2(name,count) name##count
#define IT_CHOOSER1(name,count) IT_CHOOSER2(name,count)
#define IT_CHOOSER(name,count)  IT_CHOOSER1(name,count)

#define IT_SET_ARGS_PREFIX IT_SET_ARGS_
#define IT_SET_ARGS_1( foo, arg_1) kernel.setArg(0, arg_1)
#define IT_SET_ARGS_2( foo, arg_1, arg_2) kernel.setArg(0, arg_1); kernel.setArg(1, arg_2)

...

#define IT_SET_ARGS(foo,...)\
IT_GLUE(IT_CHOOSER(IT_SET_ARGS_PREFIX,IT_N_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)), (kernel,__VA_ARGS__))
```

But i want to mention that Jarod42 solution is much better if c++11 is available.

Answer (score 1):

You may use variadic template for that:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
    void SetFoo(Foo& foo, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&... args)
    {
        int dummy[] = {0, (foo.setArg(Is, args), void(), 0)...};
        (void) dummy; // Remove warning for unused variable
    }
}

template <typename ... Ts>
void SetFoo(Foo& foo, Ts&&... args)
{
    detail::SetFoo(foo, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/HFOC2A)

or with C++17, with Folding expression:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
    void SetFoo(Foo& foo, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&... args)
    {
        (static_cast<void>(foo.setArg(Is, args)), ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a non c++11 solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I also seem to have to write code like this, but fortunately I find an alternative soon. In those cases where I have no idea, I (locally!) build macros like this (as to prevent copy-paste errors):

```
#define SET_FOO(num) foo.setArg(num, arg_##num);
SET_FOO(1)
SET_FOO(2)
#undef SET_FOO
```

Yes: it's rather primitive, and definitely no rocket-safe, but it helps.